# Excel - Exclude Cells from Computation

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, cells

Say I have 5 columns of data with 100 rows (so from A1 to E100). For each row I want to compute the averages of the 5 entries while I always exlude one of the entries. E.g. for the first row I would get the following 5 averages
=AVERAGE(B1:E1)
=AVERAGE(A1:A1,C1:E1)
=AVERAGE(A1:B1,D1:E1)
=AVERAGE(A1:C1,E1:E1)
=AVERAGE(A1:D1)
And similarly, I would obtain the averages for the other 99 rows.

Now I want to do the same with the Percentile function, but I fail to so. I would imagine something like
=PERCENTILE({A1:B1,D1:E1},0.4)
in order to compute the 40% quantile of the entries A1, B1, D1 and E1. But unfortunately, this does not work.

Does anybody know how this could be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close......

You can use a "union" in `PERCENTILE` function, i.e. a comma separated list of cell references but wrapped in ordinary parentheses, e.g.

`=PERCENTILE((A1:B1,C1:D1),0.4)`

Comment: Many thanks, this works. You mention the word "union". Is there potentially a function similar to "exclude", e.g. something like =PERCENTILE(A1:E1\C1, 0.4) which exlcudes cell C1?

Comment: No, I don't think there's a simple way to do that........